# Why does `Get-Help tree` display `Pester` topic

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know why `Get-Help tree` displays the help page for `Pester` instead of, you know, `tree`?

```
PS C:\> get-help tree
TOPIC
        Pester

SYNOPSIS
        Pester is a BDD based test runner for PowerShell.

DESCRIPTION
        Pester provides a framework for running Unit Tests to execute and validate
        PowerShell commands. Pester follows a file naming convention for naming
        tests to be discovered by pester at test time and a simple set of
        functions that expose a Testing DSL for isolating, running, evaluating and
        reporting the results of PowerShell commands.

        Pester tests can execute any command or script that is accessible to a
        pester test file. This can include functions, cmdlets, modules and scripts.
        Pester can be run in ad hoc style in a console or it can be integrated into
        the Build scripts of a Continuous Integration system.

        Pester also contains a powerful set of Mocking Functions that allow tests to
        mimic and mock the functionality of any command inside of a piece of
        PowerShell code being tested. See about_Mocking.

CREATING A PESTER TEST
        To start using Pester, you may use the New-Fixture function to scaffold both
        a new implementation function and a test function.

        C:\PS>New-Fixture deploy Clean

        Creates two files:
        ./deploy/Clean.ps1
        function clean {

        }

    ./deploy/clean.Tests.ps1
    $here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
    . "$here\$sut"

    Describe "clean" {

        It "does something useful" {
            $true | should be $false
        }
    }

    Now you have a skeleton of a clean function with a failing test. Pester
    considers all files containing *Tests.ps1 to be a test file (see
    Invoke-Pester) and by default it will look for these files and run all
    Describe blocks inside the file (See Describe). The Describe block can
    contain several behavior validations expressed in It blocks (see It).
    Each It block should test one thing and throw an exception if the test
    fails. Pester will consider any It block that throws an exception to be a
    failed test. Pester provides a set of extensions that can perform various
    comparisons between the values emitted or altered by a test and an expected
    value (see about_Should).

RUNNNING A PESTER TEST
        Once you have some logic that you are ready to test, run the Tests file directly,
        usually by pressing F5 in your ISE.

        To run multiple test files, get summary for the test run, to get nUnit compatible XML
        report or to get PesterResult object use the Invoke-Pester command. You can zero in on
        just one test (Describe block) or an entire tree of directories.

        function BuildIfChanged {
                $thisVersion=Get-Version
                $nextVersion=Get-NextVersion
                if($thisVersion -ne $nextVersion) {Build $nextVersion}
                return $nextVersion
        }

        $here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path                                                                                                                                                                                                                    $sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'                                                                                                                                                                                               . "$here\$sut"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Describe "BuildIfChanged" {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Context "When there are Changes" {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Mock Get-Version {return 1.1}
                Mock Get-NextVersion {return 1.2}
                Mock Build {} -Verifiable -ParameterFilter {$version -eq 1.2}

                $result = BuildIfChanged

                It "Builds the next version" {
                    Assert-VerifiableMocks
                }
                It "returns the next version number" {
                    $result | Should Be 1.2
                }
        }
        Context "When there are no Changes" {
                Mock Get-Version -MockWith {return 1.1}
                Mock Get-NextVersion -MockWith {return 1.1}
                Mock Build {}

                $result = BuildIfChanged

                It "Should not build the next version" {
                    Assert-MockCalled Build -Times 0 -ParameterFilter{$version -eq 1.1}
                }
        }
    }

        C:\PS>Invoke-Pester

        This will run all tests recursively from the current directory downwards
        and print a report of all failing and passing tests to the console.

PESTER AND CONTINUOUS INTEGRATION
        Pester integrates well with almost any build automation solution. You
        could create a MSBuild target that calls Pester's convenience Batch file:

        <Target Name="Tests">
        <Exec Command="cmd /c $(baseDir)pester\bin\pester.bat" />
        </Target>

        This will start a PowerShell session, import the Pester Module and call
        invoke pester within the current directory. If any test fails, it will
        return an exit code equal to the number of failed tests and all test
        results will be saved to Test.xml using NUnit's Schema allowing you to
        plug these results nicely into most Build systems like CruiseControl,
        TeamCity, TFS or Jenkins.

OTHER EXAMPLES
        Pester's own tests. See all files in the Pester Functions folder
        containing *Tests.ps1

        Chocolatey tests. Chocolatey is a popular PowerShell based Windows
        package management system. It uses Pester tests to validate its own
        functionality.

SEE ALSO
        about_Mocking
        Describe
        Context
        It
        New-Fixture
        Invoke-Pester
        about_Should
        about_TestDrive
```

I just wanted to find out what flag makes `tree` print filenames.  (It's `/f` btw.)

Comment: `Get-Help` doesn't support `.bat/.com/.cmd` scripts. Why it shows the `about_Pester` helpfile is a mystery to me though :)

Comment: Ah, I see from `get-command tree` that it is a `.com`.